# OCR not recognising text against a black background in Tess4j

Tags: selenium, tesseract, tess4j

I am not able to extract text against a black background as shown in the attached image. Everything else is getting recognised.

Can somebody please help?

[image]

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        scrShotDirPath = new File("/Users/prakashp/IdeaProjects/screenshots");
        String imgName = "15-Nov-2018_05_14_57PM.png";
        String result = null;
        File imageFile = new File(scrShotDirPath, imgName);


        logger.info("Image name is :" + imageFile.toString());
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
        File tessDataFolder = LoadLibs.extractTessResources("tessdata");
        instance.setDatapath(tessDataFolder.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            logger.info(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            logger.info("", e);
        }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: You need to update the question with your code attempts and the relevant errors (if any).

Comment: Done. Please help.